# Is FrontPage 2003 still viable in 2011?

Tags: frontpage

Should I still drive on with FrontPage, or should I bite the bullet and learn (and buy -- ouch) DreamWeaver?

I'm not a webmaster, just an amateur. My humble personal website was created years ago with FP 98 after a weekend's class and its textbook.

So I'd like to stay with FP, even if the program long ago lost its support from Microsoft.

But I've got a copy of FP2003 and a big, thick book from Microsoft Press called MS FP Inside Out.

Will websites I create, whether for non-profits or my son's business, be readable by modern browsers?

That question probably betrays my ignorance, but had to ask before I devote hours and hours to the program and the book.

Thanks.

Comment: Shoot, frontpage wasn't even viable in 2005. It's been a _joke_ for a long time now.

Comment: Also, off topic because building web pages at this level doesn't involve any programming.  If you want to program web site to run on Windows, get Visual Web Developer Express.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft also have Expression Web. In the past week or so, I replaced SpiderWriter (even older than your FrontPage) with Expression Web 4. Still learning my away around, but not as buggy as SpiderWriter and it hasn't produced obfuscated HTML (something Frontpage was infamous for).